# Слишком много JS файлов

Tags: javascript

Я пишу вэб приложение  планировщик задач без фреймворков и пытаюсь разделять элементы по компонентам, но в итоге мне кажется что получается какая то каша, так как я использую идею сингл пейдж мне приходится 90% кода писать на java script , так вот суть вопроса такова, как быть с js файлами когда их становиться слишком много и они находятся в папке каждый со своим компоненом, ели я не ошибаюсь это сильно отразится на производительности.

Comment: 1) планировщик задач© долго пытался понять что это такое 2) так как я использую идею сингл пейдж мне приходится 90% кода писать на java script© ась? 3) так вот суть вопроса такова© вынеси это, хотябы, на новую строку 4) каждый со своим компоненом© фреймворк? если да - укажи через тэг. 5) всё же не ясен вопрос. беспокоит производительность или фэншуй в дереве проекта?

Answer (score 1):

Количество файлов не особо отражается на производительности как таковой, но снижает скорость загрузки приложения (здесь основную роль играет количество http-запросов, а не файлов). Для того чтобы упаковать большой проект в пару файлов, используйте [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). На эту тему есть [скринкаст](http://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/webpack) от Ильи Кантора.

Comment: спасибо, понял. пойду изучать вебпак=)

Comment: Есть еще grunt. Он попроще помоему